# While loop using Nested if functions/statement

Tags: java, wordpress

```
import javax.Swing.JOPtionPane;
public class while looping {
 public static void main (String []args){
  String a= JOptionPane.ShowInputDialog("Please enter an Integer");
   int b=Integer.parseInt(a);
   int j=1;
   while(j<=b){
    j++;
    int k=1;
    while (k<j){
     System.out.print("*");
     k++;
    }
    System.out.println();
   }
  }
 }
}
```

This is my program and when i run it it says that `javac: invalid flag:` while what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

The "invalid flag" is probably related to the way you call the compiler. Do you call the compiler from a command line? How does the call look like?

You also have an error in your code, unrelated to the error message: you call your class "while looping". This is wrong on 2 (or 3) points: a class name must be one word, a class name must not be a reserved word ("while"), and a class name should start with a capital letter.

The last point is just a naming convention, but it makes life easier for everyone who has to read your code.

Comment: A noun and singular too?

Answer (score 0):

You can even see your error in your question with the highlighting:

```
public class while looping {
}
```

A class name may not contain any blank character.

Also it is usual to start class names with a capital letter.

Please rename your class to

```
public class WhileLooping {
}
```

and also rename your `.java` file accordingly.